# Image cropping tool for touch based phones using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, multi-touch, crop

Is there a cropping tool(marquee tool) written in javascript which would work on mobile browsers? Most of the marquee tools(cropping tool) that are written use mouse handles which would fail on touch based phones?
Any pointers in this direction?

Comment: Yeah, we are also trying to find this feature....any idea from everybody here?

Comment: I implemented my own cropping tool to suit my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jCrop from http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html is supposed to support touch events, worth a look =]

Comment: Confirmed that jCrop works for touch events on iPhone and iPad

Comment: While jCrop *does* function on touch devices, it doesn't provide the native type experience people expect: No pinch to zoom, it pans the crop area, not the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

After testing 15 small free cropping libraries from my phone, I found that this one is the only one that works reasonably well on my phone.

http://guillotine.js.org/

It does not have pinch to zoom, but maybe the lack of ambition is what makes it works well.

Warning: It has not been updated since 2015